# how to verify whether a users permissions have been revoked to execute a sp in oracle

Tags: oracle, permissions

I execute the command below to revoke a user's permissions to execute a particular SP:

```
REVOKE EXECUTE ON SOME.SP_NAME FROM SOME_USER;
```

I want a query to find out whether the execute permission has been successfully revoked.

Is there some query that will show me the all the permissions `SOME_USER` has on `SOME.SP_NAME` so that I can visually verify that `EXECUTE` isn't one of them now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [oracle query to find priveleges on a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156775/oracle-query-to-find-priveleges-on-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: @Ben: That question should also be moved to [dba.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from all_tab_privs where grantee = 'SOME_USER' and table_name = 'SP_NAME' and table_schema = 'SOME'
```

EDIT:

ALL_TAB_PRIVS works fine. Here's a session of my own:

```
SQL> create procedure myproc is begin null; end;
  2  /

Procedure created.

SQL> grant execute on myproc to x11414;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> select * from all_tab_privs where table_name = 'MYPROC';

GRANTOR                        GRANTEE                                          
------------------------------ ------------------------------                   
TABLE_SCHEMA                   TABLE_NAME                                       
------------------------------ ------------------------------                   
PRIVILEGE                                GRA HIE                                
---------------------------------------- --- ---                                
W13582                         X11414                                           
W13582                         MYPROC                                           
EXECUTE                                  NO  NO                                 


SQL> revoke execute on myproc from x11414;

Revoke succeeded.

SQL> select * from all_tab_privs where table_name = 'MYPROC';

no rows selected
```

EDIT #2: DBA_TAB_PRIVS may be better if you have access to it. ALL_TAB_PRIVS is limited to:

> Grants on objects for which the user is the grantor, grantee, owner, 
>   or an enabled role or PUBLIC is the grantee

Comment: I tried that, however, my SP isn't even present in `all_tab_privs` :(

Comment: Do any users have privileges on your stored procedure?